# AEM : Do not redirect to login page after session timeout.

Tags: aem

I have some pages that I can access without logging on, but by default, AEM will redirect to login page after session timeout, it break the logic of visit pages. Is there any way to solve this issue?

Thanks

Forrest

Answer (score 0):

This make really no sense, but I don't know exactly your requirements. The most you can do is to show the authentification form in a modal dialog, but you have to dig into sling how to break the standard behaviour (302 redirect) and return 401 instead when the request is made with ajax. Than you can build your custom authentification handler with logic like this:

- Get the authenticated state
- Check the headers for X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
- When found and not authenticated respond with 401 Unauthorized
- When not found and not authenticated redirect

Maybe [this article](http://www.wemblog.com/2013/03/how-to-create-custom-authentication.html) is useful for your case also. You can also read the answer in the [this post](http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__rkpw-hi_im_tryingto.html).